# return values between 2 given integers (Specified in main) which can be divided by 3 in a function and return answer back to main method

Tags: java, arrays, function, methods, return

Q:
**Obtain start and end integers in main method. Pass those two values into a separate function.Return all the numbers between those values (inclusive), which is divisible by 3 back to the main from the function.** 
I have done upto:

```
import java.util.*;
public class inbetween {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter range of values");
        int x =in.nextInt();
        int y =in.nextInt();
        search(x,y);

    }

    public static void search(int a, int b) {
          int length = (b-a)+1;
        int [] arr = new int [length];
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
          a = a+1;
         int c;
         // int count=0;
          c = a%3;
          if (c==0) {
              arr[i] = a;
          System.out.println(arr[i]);
       //   count = count+1;
       //   return count;

        }
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is ..How can I return the array and print it in function and print it there??? this code works but in this, the values are getting printed in the function itself (but it should be printed in the main)...

Comment: This is a very basic Java programming question, and probably doesn't demonstrate the minimal understanding of the language that's expected of a StackOverflow question.  It sounds like your `search` method needs to store the divisible values in an `int[]` (or a Collection), and return it.

Comment: Please try not to be MEAN!

Comment: That wasn't intended to be mean. An official reason for closing questions is that "Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist".  Your main question is "How can I return the array?"  The Java tutorials cover [Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html), which probably answers your question.

Comment: Thank you! I am yet a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
import java.util.*;
public class inbetween {
public static void main (String[]args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter range of values");
    int x =in.nextInt();
    int y =in.nextInt();
    int[] result = search(x,y);
    for (int i=0;i < result.length; i++)
      System.out.println(result[i]);
}

public static int[] search(int a, int b) {
      int length = (b-a)+1;
    int [] arr = new int [length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
      a = a+1;
     int c;
     // int count=0;
      c = a%3;
      if (c==0) {
          arr[i] = a;
              }
    }
    return arr;
}
}
```

Comment: How can i elminate the zeros?????

Comment: @user2750830: check my answer, I've used `Arrays.copyOfRange` there to eliminate zeros.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create array in main
2. Pass reference to array to function to do work
3. Print array out in main

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an array to main:

```
package com.stackoverflow.homework;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] result;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter range of values: ");
        int x = in.nextInt();
        int y = in.nextInt();

        result = findNumbersBetween(x,y);

        for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(result[i]);
        }

    }

    private static int[] findNumbersBetween(int a, int b) {
        int[] temp = new int[(b-a)+1];
        int x = a;
        int i = 0;

        while(x <= b) {
            if(x % 3 == 0) {
                temp[i] = x;
                i++;
            }

            x++;
        }

        return Arrays.copyOfRange(temp, 0, i);
    }
}
```

Also remember that first letter of class name should always be capitalized!